# Examine the eigenvalues of a linear map that has only two invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

> Let V be a vector space (over $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ of $\mathbb{C}$)
> of dimension $n\geqslant 2$, such that $f$ has only
> $\{0_V\}$ and $V$ as it's invariant subspaces. Examine if $f$ has eigenvalues.

**Attempt.** If $\lambda\in \mathbb{F}$ is an eigenvalue of $f$, then eigenspace
$V_f(\lambda)\neq \{0_V\}$ is invariant subspace of $f$ and $V_f(\lambda)=V$, by hypothesis, i.e. $f=\lambda I_V$ ($I_V(v)=v$ the identity map over $V$). So we would say that either $f$ has no eigenvalues, either $f=\lambda I_V$ and $\lambda$ is it's unique eigenvalue.

Is  the argument correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, not correct. The identity map has many, many invariant subspaces.

Comment: Indeed, every subspace of $V$ is an invariant subspace of the  identity map. In our case, since $V$ has dimension n greater than 2, it is enough to choose a one dimensional subspace of $V$, which would be an invariant subspace of the identity map, while $f$ has no invariant subspaces except the trivial and $V,$ contradiction. So $f$ has no eigenvalues.

Comment: I would argue that since the question specified $\Bbb F=\Bbb R$ versus $\Bbb C$, one should stop to discuss the case that, working over $\Bbb R$, $f$ has *complex* eigenvalues. Officially, eigenvalues should live in $\Bbb F$, but there is more to say here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An eigenvector of $f$ can be defined as a vector spanning a $1$-dimensional $f$-invariant subspace. Since your hypotheses exclude such subspaces, there can be no eigenvectors (and hence no eigenvalues).